anyOf two sets of patternProperties but no additionalProperties
I am attempting to define two possible sets of patternProperties using anyOf, but I would like to exclude any properties that don't fit either of those patterns. However, when defining additionalProperties: false after the two sets of patternProperties, I get an error that none of the properties match.
Here is some sample JSON data:
{
  "fruitbasket": {
    "apple": {
      "color": "green"
    },
    "pear": {
      "color": "green"
    },
    "banana": {
      "color": "yellow"
    },
    "apple_wrapper": {
      "material": "paper"
    },
    "pear_wrapper": {
      "material": "cloth"
    },
    "banana_wrapper": {
      "material": "none"
    }
  }
}

And here is my schema:
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/responseobject",
  "definitions": {
    "responseobject": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "fruitbasket": {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/fruit"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/wrapper"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "fruit": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^(apple|pear|banana)$": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "color": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "green",
                "yellow",
                "red"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "color"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "wrapper": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^(apple|pear|banana)_wrapper$": {
          "properties": {
            "material": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "paper",
                "cloth",
                "none"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "material"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}

If I remove "additionalProperties": false that is defined alongside even just one of the two patternProperties the schema validates. Is this level of strictness even possible in the current JSON schema? How should I go about allowing only two sets of patternProperties and no other property?
Here is an online validation example showing the errors: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/DQqnlLBT

Yes, you can remove the anyOf and have multiple patternProperties but you have undefined behavior for draft-07 when using $ref at the root of the schema, it must be wrapped in an allOf to be validated successfully, per the Specification.
Only after 2019-09 was a root $ref allowed by the Specification.
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/responseobject"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "responseobject": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "fruitbasket": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "patternProperties": {
                        "^(apple|pear|banana)$": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "color": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "enum": [
                                        "green",
                                        "yellow",
                                        "red"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "color"
                            ],
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },
                        "^(apple|pear|banana)_wrapper$": {
                            "properties": {
                                "material": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "enum": [
                                        "paper",
                                        "cloth",
                                        "none"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "material"
                            ],
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        }
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}


passing instance
{
    "fruitbasket": {
        "apple": {
            "color": "green"
        },
        "pear_wrapper": {
            "material": "paper"
        }
    }
}

failing instance
{
    "fruitbasket": {
        "apple": {
            "color": "green"
        },
        "pears": {},
        "pear_wrapper": {
            "material": "paper"
        }
    }
}


if you want to componentize the definitions, they can be defined separately, I just put them inline for the answer.

Actually I think I found the answer. No need to use anyOf, just put the patternProperties one after the other:
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/responseobject",
  "definitions": {
    "responseobject": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "fruitbasket": {
          "type": "object",
          "patternProperties": {
            "^(apple|pear|banana)$": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/fruit"
            },
            "^(apple|pear|banana)_wrapper$": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/wrapper"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      }
    },
    "fruit": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "color": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "green",
            "yellow",
            "red"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "color"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "wrapper": {
      "properties": {
        "material": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "paper",
            "cloth",
            "none"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "material"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}

